# Fanfic where Harry is born in the 1920s and is sent to Wool's orphanage

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

This is a Tomarry (Tom + Harry) fic where Harry is born in the 1920s and he's sent to Wool's orphanage but is selectively mute and clings to Tom.

He's possessive and controlling of Harry but Harry doesn't mind. In this they are separated by the World War and end up again in the war in a desert. Tom almost dies but gets rescued by some mysterious clan in the desert and comes back with a demon in his soul.

Cue their return to civilisation and netting the Malfoys who kidnap Harry to get to Tom as they are in the demon business as well.

I don't remember much more about the story than that. I think it was complete. It's been bugging me for weeks!

Comment: Do you remember how long ago you read this? Perhaps what site it might have been on?